# PayPal Intergration with BootStrap Pricing Table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, paypal

So Im Working on my services portion of my website and I Wanted to include a Shopping Cart.... Then I thought about it. I dont want a shopping cart I want to use my bootstrap 3 pricing tables and use the buttons to add to paypal cart. Then I think to use paypal create a button but the paypal button customization is calling for an actual image and the Bootstrap is all html. Is there anyways I can get my Bootstrap button to add a specific item to my custom designed cart page?

Can I display the cart in a lightbox so the user Never has to leave my website?

```
<div class="panel price panel-red">
                    <div class="panel-heading  text-center">
                    <h3>PRO PLAN</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-center">
                        <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong>$10 / month</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Personal use</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> Unlimited projects</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i> 27/7 support</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" href="#">BUY NOW!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've got several questions here, which makes it hard for us to answer, and it'll be hard for you to track which of them has been answered. Why don't you pick one question to start with and give us more info about that. Any other important questions can go into another Stack Overflow Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is go through the button creation wizard, and during that process (I think towards the end) you'll have the option to create a regular button or an email link for the payment.

If you choose the email link it will give you a general URL that can be used instead of a button/form.  This URL could be hooked up to your Bootstrap button like any other link and when clicked it will send the user into a payment flow.